# List of modules in Windows X64. ProcessModuleCollection

Tags: c#, 64-bit

**This code does not find x32 dlls in Windows X64:**

```
public int DllImageAddress(string dllname)
    {
        ProcessModuleCollection modules = MyProcess[0].Modules;

        foreach (ProcessModule procmodule in modules)
        {
            if (procmodule.ModuleName.IndexOf(dllname) != -1)
            {
                return (int)procmodule.BaseAddress;
            }
        }
        return -1;

    }
```

How to get a list of x32 modules in Windows 7 x64 ?

(example: DllImageAddress("Mydll.dll") in Windows 7 X86 returns not -1, in x64 returns -1)

Comment: The question is very vague.  There are typically *thousands* of DLLs present on a 64-bit operating system.  Only *some* of which will ever be loaded by a process.  With low odds in general, most running processes are 64-bit processes and they cannot load a 32-bit DLL.  Your code not doing a case-insensitive compare and not accounting for 32-bit DLLs being subjected to file system redirection from system32 to syswow64 increase the odds of never getting a match.

Comment: I do not understand how it will help me to fix the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am nut 100% sure but you will probably have to use `EnumProcessModule`. There is a filter option `LIST_MODULES_32BIT` in there. Just take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682633(v=vs.85).aspx.

You may also want to take a look at the C# signature at http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/psapi.enumprocessmodules.

EDIT:
For Windows XP `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` should be sufficient with the `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32` flag.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Minimum supported client
Windows Vista [desktop apps only]
Minimum supported server
Windows Server 2008 [desktop apps only]

Comment: My program will be for WinXP +

Comment: I'll try to find a solution elsewhere :(

(I had to get with c # list all modules in x64 and in x86)